# Windows 10 and Edge

Tags: microsoft-edge

I need to 'downgrade' Internet Explorer. I need to use a different older version with the software that my school district uses for special education students. Any ideas on what I can do?

I have a Windows 10 laptop with Edge.

Comment: specific older version or any older version? IE11 is still available on Windows 10

Comment: Microsoft Edge is different than Internet Explorer, as it uses the metro side of windows. Try searching for "Internet Explorer" as it should be on the system as well, just semi-hard to find.

Comment: Also another thing to note, as of January 12th, 2016 Microsoft reached end of support for anything below IE11. End of support does not mean the software stops working. When a given deadline is reached for its software, Microsoft simply stops releasing security updates and offering technical support. You can download specific versions of IE [here](http://www.oldapps.com/internet_explorer.php)

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer 11 is still available in Windows 10.  However, it is probably not on the start menu or task bar by default.   To get to IE11, either enter "Internet Explorer" at the Contana/Search bar (or use the start menu's "All apps", and navigate to "Windows Accessories").

Once you've found IE11, you can then pin it to the start menu / taskbar if you like.

IE11 has an extensive emulation capability via the "F12" developer tools.  You can use this to make IE11 "look like" a previous version of IE.  So, for example, you can make it look like IE7 by changing both the "Document mode" and "User Agent" settings as shown:

[image]